# Why is space removed before # in Laravel Mail?

Tags: php, laravel-5

My Mail Subject is "Brand1 #4 New ticket comment"

However, When I receive an email it remove a space before #. Something like this "Brand1#4 New ticket comment"

If I put any other special character like @, it work fine. Any Idea?

Below is the code where I create Subject String for Email.

```
> $params['appName'].'     #'.$support_ticket->id.' New ticket comment';
```

Any Idea what is the issue ?

> Laravel 5.2
>
> PHP 7.0.31

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&nbsp;` like this :

```
$params['appName']."&nbsp;#".$support_ticket->id." New ticket comment";
```

I also changed `'` to `"`

Comment: It's not working. Output is like this "Sushi Shack\n#4 New ticket comment" nor with "&nbsp;" it's working.

Comment: Try  change ' to "

Comment: '' & "" doesn't make any different output in my situation.

Comment: But in your first commentary :" nor with "&nbsp;" it's working."
It's working no ?

Comment: Then you misunderstood, What I mean to say was its not working with anything you have mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187180/discussion-between-vishal-tarkar-and-maxime-pomier).

Answer (score 0):

If the `#` is the problem character you could try using it's html entity code `&#35;` instead.

Comment: I have tried that too & its not working, As problem is not in displaying "#" but it's remove space before is.